# Getting null values on submitting data using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is the ajax code I have. I do not know where is the problem why it keeps on giving me null values.

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(event) {
    var formData = {
        'name'              : $('input[name=name1]').val(),
        'branch_address'    : $('input[name=bAddress1]').val(),
        'officer_in_charge' : $('input[name=officer1]').val(),
        'contact_number'    : $('input[name=contactN1]').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
         type        : 'POST',
         dataType    : 'json',
         url         : "process_save.php",
         data        : formData,
         encode      : true

        })
}
```

And the input values came from here

```
<form id="form1">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name1" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bAddress1" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="officer1" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactN1" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn" />
    </div>
</form>
```

process_save.php contains this code

```
if( !empty( $_POST ) ){
        // convert form data to json format
        $data = array(
          "name" => $_POST['name1'],
          "branch_address" => $_POST['bAddress1'],
          "officer_in_charge" => $_POST['officer1'],
          "contact_number" => $_POST['contactN1']
        ); //processes the fields on the form

        $json = json_encode( $data );
        $file = 'entries.json';
        // write to file
        file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Try using `JSON.stringify()`, modify ajax request data as `data : JSON.stringify(formData) ,`

Comment: it did not work @KartikeyaKhosla

Comment: You renamed `name1` to `name` -> `'name' : $('input[name=name1]').val(),`, so why do you have `"name" => $_POST['name1'],` instead of `"name" => $_POST['name'],`. This goes for all your other vars as well

Comment: did not notice that one. thanks @Sean

Comment: change `$json = json_encode( $data );` to `$json = json_encode( $_POST );`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your php code is using the original names of the form inputs, not the names in your `var formData`. So change your php `$_POST` keys to the `var formData` keys -

javascript code-

```
// use these keys
var formData = {
    'name'              : $('input[name=name1]').val(),
    'branch_address'    : $('input[name=bAddress1]').val(),
    'officer_in_charge' : $('input[name=officer1]').val(),
    'contact_number'    : $('input[name=contactN1]').val()
};
```

php code-

```
    // as the $_POST keys
    $data = array(
      "name" => $_POST['name'],
      "branch_address" => $_POST['branch_address'],
      "officer_in_charge" => $_POST['officer_in_charge'],
      "contact_number" => $_POST['contact_number']
    );
```